# . htaccess not working in server

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, clean-url

Hi
My web server is Apache.I have created a sample application in my local system. It's working fine with the clean url. But when i uploaded to my Web server( Apache) it's not working. Is there is any settings in Apache? If yes what are the steps? How can I check is mod_rewrite is enable in my Apache server? is it any way to know "mod_rewrite is on " through any PHP coding?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "not working"  is not a great description of the issue.

Comment: I got a 404 page not found error while running my script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way to know "mod_rewrite is on " through any PHP coding?

Yes, create a php page with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. This lists your server configuration. Under the `apache2handler` section in "Loaded Modules" you should see `mod_rewrite` if it is installed.

If it isn't listed there you will either need to ask your host or if you have access, see the apache modules-enabled folder (eg in /etc/apache2 on a standard installation) to see if there is a mod_rewrite listed.

Comment: did you leave out phpinfo(); ??

Comment: heh, thanks - not sure what happened there.. maybe it picked up the braces and stripped the tag.

Comment: I have a php info page see http://kluzusa.com/php-info.ph. But from here I can't see mod_rewrite.  Which indicates it's not enabled. Is it? Also my web site is live site. SO I want to make mod_rewrite only in a folder named url. If activate mod_rewrite by hosting is there any problem in my existing pages?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely *mod_rewrite* is enabled. If it is not, you will probably need to contact your hosting company to activate it OR override the servers default with *RewriteEngine On* in your .htacces. Are you getting a 500, Internal Server Error when you try to run the script?

And if it was not compiled (or they can't provide it) with php, then maybe its time to find a new host?

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache on Ubuntu or DEBIAN write this code in Terminal:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and restarting apache

```
sudo invoke-rc.d apache2 restart
```