# Block domain to redirect the particular site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, block

One of my competitor redirect my site to their own site.I need .ht access code to block that.SO,that no one can redirect my site.

Comment: I think redirection is not possible without editing in code. tell us the condition in which your site is redirecting.

Comment: my competitor redirect the site through cpanel

Comment: I tried                      RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} badsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]  BUT it's not working

Comment: how can they have access of your cpanel. if they have change the details ASAP. and check for redirection in cpanel

Comment: do you have cpanel details?

Comment: no,they reditect their own site to my site

Comment: Suppose my site is abc.com and my competitor site xyz.com.When I click on xyz.com, my site is open

Comment: I think no harm for you in this conditions .

Comment: It will goes down my ranking

Comment: is there any htaccess code to block such type of work

Comment: try this for generating http://incredibill.me/htaccess-block-referer

Comment: # BLOCK SITE REFERRERS
RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} lilacs\.biz [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]           not working.my site is thirdeyewebdesign.in

Comment: is my updated answer is working for you?

Comment: # BLOCK SITE REFERRERS
RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} lilacs\.biz [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} www\.lilacs\.biz [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} http\://lilacs\.biz [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} http\://www\.lilacs\.biz [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]

it's not working

Comment: check your server for htaceess, is it enable or not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709893/htaccess-not-working-in-server

Comment: pls give me your contact number.I hv sent you message on facebook

Answer (score 0):

as per your comments I think your website is redirecting by the cpanel option `redirects`.

[image]

check this option. 
redirecting might be due to this.

[image]

no `htaccess` will work in this condition.

> Update

for htacccess

```
# BLOCK SITE REFERRERS
RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} badsite\.com [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} www\.badsite\.com [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} http\://badsite\.com [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} http\://www\.badsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

**I also suggest you to change the login details of your cpanel ASAP**